# Calculating time windows for entities

Tags: c#, performance, generics, reflection, interval

I have made some code that operates on multiple entities and creates 'time windows' for them. Basically, the entities will contain states, usually in boolean or int. They will be timestamped and in order to reduce the number of rows when creating a graph for a large date range, I am calculating time windows of 5 mins, 15 mins and 60 mins. If I'm calculating the 5 minute time windows, and a state is true from 00:00:00 to 00:02:59 and false from 00:03:00 onwards, the time window for the first 5 minutes of the day would be true, since the state was true for 3 out of 5 minutes.

I have used custom attributes, generics and reflection in order to check what properties the entities have and which of them I need to process.

The code works, but I'm sure it can be improved.

Sometimes, the code works fast for a couple of thousands of rows across 16 entities, i.e. 16 calls to the `CalculateTimeWindows<T>()` method (less than a second) but sometimes it's really slow (takes some 45 seconds). Any ideas how I can optimise this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Services.Helpers
{
    #region Custom Attributes
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class DoNotCopyIntoTimeWindow : System.Attribute { } // leave default

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow : System.Attribute { } // calculate time window for this property

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class IsTimeWindowDate : Attribute { } // attribute to mark property as the datetime

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class IsTimeWindowIdentifier : Attribute { } // this is the time window property
    #endregion

    public class TimeWindow
    {
        #region Structs
        public struct TimeWindowDictionary
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<NullObject<dynamic>, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
        }

        public struct NullObject<T>
        {
            [DefaultValue(true)]
            private readonly bool isnull;// default property initializers are not supported for structs

            private NullObject(T item, bool isnull) : this()
            {
                this.isnull = isnull;
                Item = item;
            }

            public NullObject(T item) : this(item, item == null)
            {
            }

            public static NullObject<T> Null()
            {
                return new NullObject<T>();
            }

            public T Item { get; private set; }

            public bool IsNull()
            {
                return isnull;
            }

            public static implicit operator T(NullObject<T> nullObject)
            {
                return nullObject.Item;
            }

            public static implicit operator NullObject<T>(T item)
            {
                return new NullObject<T>(item);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return (Item != null) ? Item.ToString() : "NULL";
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return IsNull();

                if (!(obj is NullObject<T>))
                    return false;

                var no = (NullObject<T>)obj;

                if (IsNull())
                    return no.IsNull();

                if (no.IsNull())
                    return false;

                return Item.Equals(no.Item);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                if (IsNull())
                    return 0;

                var result = Item.GetHashCode();

                if (result >= 0)
                    result++;

                return result;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public static IEnumerable<T> CalculateTimeWindows<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels) where T : new()
        {
            if (stateModels.Count() == 0)
                return new List<T>();

            dateFrom = GetPropertiesAndDictionaries(dateFrom, stateModels, out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo, out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties, out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier, out int size, out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries, out int i);

            return CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 5, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i)
                        .Concat(CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 15, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i))
                        .Concat(CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 60, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> CalculateTimeWindow<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels, byte timeWindowMinutes, PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo, List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties, PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier, int size, TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries, int i) where T : new()
        {
            if (stateModels.Count() > 0)
            {
                DateTime currentWindowFrom, currentWindowTo, nextWindowFrom;
                nextWindowFrom = dateFrom;
                int itemPointer = 0;
                T prevItem = default;
                T prevTimeWindow = default;

                KeyValuePair<NullObject<dynamic>, int> maxValue = new KeyValuePair<NullObject<dynamic>, int>();
                int j = 1;

                do // one time window
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        dictionaries[i].Dictionary = new Dictionary<NullObject<dynamic>, int>();

                    currentWindowFrom = nextWindowFrom;
                    nextWindowFrom = currentWindowFrom.AddMinutes(timeWindowMinutes);
                    currentWindowTo = nextWindowFrom.AddSeconds(-1);

                    var calculateTime = currentWindowFrom;

                    for (itemPointer = itemPointer; itemPointer < stateModels.Count(); itemPointer++)
                    {
                        var item = stateModels.ElementAt(itemPointer);

                        var date = (DateTime)datePropertyInfo.GetValue(item);

                        if (date >= currentWindowTo)
                            break;

                        var endDate = (date > currentWindowTo) ? nextWindowFrom : date; // state might extend more than the end of the time window
                        CalculateStateSeconds(prevItem, dictionaries, calculateTime, endDate);

                        prevItem = item;
                        calculateTime = (date < currentWindowFrom) ? currentWindowFrom : date; // to fix the 'yesterday' date
                    }

                    if (calculateTime < currentWindowTo)
                        CalculateStateSeconds(prevItem, dictionaries, calculateTime, nextWindowFrom);

                    if (dictionaries[0].Dictionary.Count > 0)
                    {
                        bool sameAsPrevious = (prevTimeWindow != null);
                        var output = new T();

                        foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
                        {
                            //var valToSet = dictionary.Dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(dictionary.Dictionary.Values.Max())).Key.Item;

                            for (i = 0; i < dictionary.Dictionary.Count; i++)
                            {
                                maxValue = dictionary.Dictionary.First();
                                for (j = 1; j < dictionary.Dictionary.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    var valuePair = dictionary.Dictionary.ElementAt(j);

                                    if (valuePair.Value > maxValue.Value)
                                        maxValue = valuePair;
                                }
                            }
                            var valToSet = maxValue.Key.Item;

                            if (sameAsPrevious)
                            {
                                var prevVal = GetValue(prevTimeWindow, dictionary.Name);

                                if (valToSet == null && prevVal == null)
                                { }
                                else if ((valToSet == null && prevVal != null) || (valToSet != null && prevVal == null) || !valToSet.Equals(prevVal))
                                    sameAsPrevious = false;
                            }

                            SetValue(output, dictionary.Name, valToSet);
                        }

                        if (!sameAsPrevious)
                        {
                            foreach (var copyProperty in copyProperties)
                                SetValue(output, copyProperty.Name, copyProperty.GetValue(prevItem));

                            timeWindowIdentifier.SetValue(output, timeWindowMinutes);

                            datePropertyInfo.SetValue(output, currentWindowFrom);

                            prevTimeWindow = output;

                            yield return output;
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (nextWindowFrom <= dateTo);
            }
        }

        private static DateTime GetPropertiesAndDictionaries<T>(DateTime dateFrom, List<T> stateModels, out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo, out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties, out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier, out int size, out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries, out int i) where T : new()
        {
            Type tType = typeof(T);
            var propInfos = tType.GetProperties();

            datePropertyInfo = propInfos.Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowDate), true).Any());
            var firstDate = (DateTime)datePropertyInfo.GetValue(stateModels.First());

            if (firstDate < dateFrom)
                dateFrom = new DateTime(firstDate.Year, firstDate.Month, firstDate.Day, firstDate.Hour, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

            var properties = propInfos.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow), true).Any()).Select(x => x.Name);
            copyProperties = propInfos.Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowIdentifier), true).Any() && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotCopyIntoTimeWindow), true).Any() && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowDate), true).Any() && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow), true).Any() && p.CanWrite && !p.GetMethod.IsVirtual).ToList();
            timeWindowIdentifier = propInfos.Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowIdentifier), true).Any());

            size = properties.Count();
            dictionaries = new TimeWindowDictionary[size];

            i = 0;
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                dictionaries[i] = new TimeWindowDictionary() { Name = property };
                i++;
            }

            return dateFrom;
        }

        private static dynamic GetValue(object inputObject, string propertyName)
        {
            Type type = inputObject.GetType();
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return propertyInfo.GetValue(inputObject);
        }

        private static void SetValue(object inputObject, string propertyName, object propertyVal)
        {
            //find out the type
            Type type = inputObject.GetType();

            //get the property information based on the type
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (propertyVal != null)
            {
                //find the property type
                Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

                //Convert.ChangeType does not handle conversion to nullable types
                //if the property type is nullable, we need to get the underlying type of the property
                var targetType = IsNullableType(propertyType) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) : propertyType;

                //Returns an System.Object with the specified System.Type and whose value is
                //equivalent to the specified object.
                propertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(propertyVal, targetType);
            }

            //Set the value of the property
            propertyInfo.SetValue(inputObject, propertyVal, null);

        }

        private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
        {
            return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
        }

        private static void CalculateStateSeconds<T>(T prevItem, IEnumerable<TimeWindowDictionary> dictionaries, DateTime calculateTime, DateTime endDate)
        {
            if (prevItem != null)
            {
                var seconds = Convert.ToInt32(endDate.Subtract(calculateTime).TotalSeconds);

                Type tType = typeof(T);

                foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = tType.GetProperty(dictionary.Name);
                    var key = propertyInfo.GetValue(prevItem);

                    dictionary.Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out int existingSeconds);
                    dictionary.Dictionary[key] = existingSeconds + seconds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample class and Unit test:

```
public abstract class MyBaseModel : ICloneable
{
    [DoNotCopyIntoTimeWindow]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public short fk_TenantId { get; set; }

    [IsTimeWindowIdentifier]
    public byte TimeWindow { get; set; }

    [IsTimeWindowDate]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow]
    public byte ActuallyAnEnum { get; set; }

    public abstract bool CalculatorOn { get; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class MyModel : MyBaseModel
{
    public short ShortId { get; set; }
    public short AnotherShortId { get; set; }

    [IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public override bool CalculatorOn
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestLowerResolution()
{
    /* generate test data */
    DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2018, 1, 28, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var dateTo = dateFrom.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

    var myValues = new List<MyModel>();

    myValues.Add(new MyModel()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 9, 15, 48, 46, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        ShortId = 5,
        AnotherShortId = 0,
        TimeWindow = 0,
        Value = 30,
        fk_TenantId = 1006
    });

    myValues.Add(new MyModel()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 29, 10, 11, 31, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        ShortId = 5,
        AnotherShortId = 0,
        TimeWindow = 0,
        Value = 14336,
        fk_TenantId = 1006
    });

    myValues.Add(new MyModel()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 29, 10, 11, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        ShortId = 5,
        AnotherShortId = 0,
        TimeWindow = 0,
        Value = 30,
        fk_TenantId = 1006
    });

    var windows = TimeWindow.CalculateTimeWindows(dateFrom, dateTo, myValues).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated code at [Performance issue with empty lists](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/performance-issue-with-empty-lists)

Comment: Interesting question. You could make it easier for reviewers to follow, if you provide a simple working test case also showing the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikHansen, I've just done so.

Comment: Your code is hard to read because of the many lengthy lines. A couple of line-breaks would greatly improve its readability.

Comment: @t3chb0t, better now?

Comment: mhmm... only a little

Comment: @t3chb0t, re-ordered further.

Comment: @dfhwze, changed the `myValues` part, thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify this: _If I'm calculating the 5 minute time windows, and a state is true from 00:00:00 to 00:02:59 and false from 00:03:00 onwards_ - why isn't the sate valid until 00:04:59 which would be _almost_ 5 minutes but some other random number? Why do you just have 5, 15, and 60 steps instead of any number spanning between two timestamps? Why do you need all these attributes? It'd be much easier to use an interface and where the properties don't match it just create _dummy_ properties on your entities to map to the actual ones. I find this solution is currently super complex o_O

Comment: @t3chb0t, I need these steps to reduce resolution. Typically, hundreds of thousands of rows could be retrieved and would need to be plotted onto a graph that is obviously going to be restricted by the amount of horizontal pixels on screen. The process is slow and in order to make it faster, depending on the timeframe required, I decide whether to SELECT those with TimeWindow=0, 5, 15 or 60. The graph looks virtually the same, and then you can zoom in to a section and it would get a lower resolution, perhaps TimeWindow=0 (the real data).

Comment: One thing I didn't add is that if 2 rows are the same, say an entity only has a boolean and it spends 2 hours in that state, it won't create an entry every 5 minutes for TimeWindow=5, but still one until the next 5 minute timeframe where the state changes.

Comment: I still doubt you need that much reflection. Could you add some of the real entities you are working with so that we have the full picture? Do they really all have different properties?

Comment: There's some 10 different entities, @t3chb0t, with an average of around 4 properties each (for which the TimeWindow needs to be calculated). The whole idea of using reflection was to avoid adding additional maintenance that needs to be done if a property is added or removed from an entity, apart from adding a custom attribute at most. It reduces the chance of a developer forgetting to need to do something else in another place. That's why reflection was used. And yes, all properties are different, and I'd rather not reveal the entities here because it's a bit sensitive.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti You don't need to reveal the entities, but the current trivial example is not clear. I hope you find a way to visualise how exactly you want the algorithm to slice data in time.

Comment: @dfhwze let's say you're manually calculating a time window for 17:40 to 17:45. You  check if there is an entry with the date exactly 17:40:00. If not, you check the one before that. Now you know that at 17:40:00 all properties would have been according to this entry. Now you check all DB rows until and including 17:44:59 and you build a dictionary with values of each property and the amount of seconds they spent with that value during this time window. It's a sort of popularity contest. The value with the highest amount of seconds for each property wins.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I understand what you want now, thanks. I would normally solve this with a view or stored procedure, but I can assert you only want a C# solution?

Comment: Yes @dfhwze, because despite me talking about entities and DB rows, they're actually items that have just been processed from something else and have not yet even been inserted in a database. When I insert, I insert not just the ones with TimeWindow=0 (the real data), but all of the time window data. So as such, this code is purely LINQ to objects.

Comment: I went through your code and like you... I have absolutely no idea what you are doing there and why. There are so many classes, structs and properties and logic that you have not described that it is virtually incomprihensible without reverse-engineering it for a couple of hours. I wish you luck in optimizing it, you'll need a lot of it :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t I feel the same way. There is no beginning this task. Respect to the reviewers that take a shot at this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>     var firstDate = (DateTime)datePropertyInfo.GetValue(stateModels.First());
>
>     if (firstDate < dateFrom)
>       dateFrom = new DateTime(firstDate.Year, firstDate.Month, firstDate.Day, firstDate.Hour, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
> ```

You take the first stateModel, but what if they are not ordered by date?

---

> ```
> for (itemPointer = itemPointer; itemPointer < stateModels.Count(); itemPointer++)
> ```

`itemPointer = itemPointer` isn't neccesary:

```
for (; itemPointer < stateModels.Count(); itemPointer++)
```

---

The last parameter to `CalculateTimeWindow<T>(..., ..., int i)` is initialized with the `out int i` parameter from `GetPropertiesAndDictionaries()`, but the values is actually not used and `i` is used as an iterator index set to `0` the first time used, so why have it as a parameter and not just a local variable? Get rid of that, if it's not used.

---

This:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> CalculateTimeWindows<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels) where T : new()
    {
        if (stateModels.Count() == 0)
            return new List<T>();

        dateFrom = GetPropertiesAndDictionaries(dateFrom, stateModels, out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo, out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties, out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier, out int size, out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries, out int i);

        return CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 5, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i)
                    .Concat(CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 15, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i))
                    .Concat(CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, 60, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i));
    }
```

I would write as:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> CalculateTimeWindows<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels) where T : new()
  {
    if (stateModels == null || stateModels.Count() == 0)
      yield break; // return new List<T>();

    dateFrom = GetPropertiesAndDictionaries(
      dateFrom, 
      stateModels, 
      out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo, 
      out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties, 
      out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier, 
      out int size, 
      out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries, 
      out int i);

    byte[] windowDurations = { 5, 15, 60 };

    foreach (byte duration in windowDurations)
    {
      foreach (T result in CalculateTimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels, duration, datePropertyInfo, copyProperties, timeWindowIdentifier, size, dictionaries, i))
      {
        yield return result;
      }
    }
```

or as:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> CalculateTimeWindows<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels) where T : new()
  {
    if (stateModels.Count() == 0)
      return new List<T>();

    dateFrom = GetPropertiesAndDictionaries(
      dateFrom,
      stateModels,
      out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo,
      out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties,
      out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier,
      out int size,
      out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries,
      out int i);

    byte[] windowDurations = { 5, 15, 60 };

    return windowDurations.SelectMany(wd =>
      CalculateTimeWindow(
        dateFrom,
        dateTo,
        stateModels,
        wd,
        datePropertyInfo,
        copyProperties,
        timeWindowIdentifier,
        size,
        dictionaries,
        i));
   }
```

It is much more readable and easy to maintain if you want to add a new time window.

---

```
    copyProperties = propInfos
      .Where(
        p => 
          !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowIdentifier), true).Any() 
          && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotCopyIntoTimeWindow), true).Any() 
          && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsTimeWindowDate), true).Any() 
          && !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow), true).Any() 
          && p.CanWrite 
          && !p.GetMethod.IsVirtual).ToList();
```

In the above you determine which properties to fetch data from in a negative way by checking what they are not. I think, I would define a `ValuePropertyAttribute` to mark the properties to get data from with. It is easier to maintain, because you'll always be able to see from this attribute which properties values are copied from on an object.

---

When handling properties (setting and getting) there is a little too much conversion between `PropertyInfo`s and `string`s (names) IMO.

You can reduce that by changing the definition of:

```
  public struct TimeWindowDictionary
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<NullObject<dynamic>, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
  }
```

to

```
  public struct TimeWindowDictionary
  {
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<NullObject<dynamic>, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
  }
```

and then change everything to accomodate to that - for instance:

```
    var properties = propInfos.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow), true).Any()).Select(x => x.Name);
    size = properties.Count();

    dictionaries = new TimeWindowDictionary[size];
    i = 0;

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
      dictionaries[i] = new TimeWindowDictionary() { Name = property };
      i++;
    }
```

could be:

```
    dictionaries =
      propInfos
      .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsProcessedIntoTimeWindow), true).Any())
      .Select(p => new TimeWindowDictionary { PropertyInfo = p })
      .ToArray();

    size = dictionaries.Length;
```

and `GetValue(...)` could be:

```
  private static dynamic GetValue(object inputObject, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
  {
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(inputObject);
    //Type type = inputObject.GetType();
    //System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    //return propertyInfo.GetValue(inputObject);
  }
```

and `SetValue(...)` could likewise have the signature:

```
  private static void SetValue(object inputObject, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object propertyVal)
```

and in `CalculateStateSeconds<T>(...)`:

```
        //PropertyInfo propertyInfo = tType.GetProperty(dictionary.Name);
        var key = dictionary.PropertyInfo.GetValue(prevItem);
        dictionary.Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out int existingSeconds);
        dictionary.Dictionary[key] = existingSeconds + seconds;
```

---

```
  private static DateTime GetPropertiesAndDictionaries<T>(
    DateTime dateFrom,
    List<T> stateModels,
    out PropertyInfo datePropertyInfo,
    out List<PropertyInfo> copyProperties,
    out PropertyInfo timeWindowIdentifier,
    out int size,
    out TimeWindowDictionary[] dictionaries,
    out int i) where T : new()
  {
```

When having all these arguments passed from method to method, I think I would make a container object for them and pass that instead. Alternatively you could make the class statefull with these parameters as members instead, so you can avoid having arguments to the methods at all. The methods should then be non static members of course. Your one and only static method could then be something like:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetTimeWindows<T>(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<T> stateModels) where T : new()
  {
    TimeWindow timeWindow = new TimeWindow(dateFrom, dateTo, stateModels);
    return timeWindow.Calculate();
  }
```

where the `TimeWindow` class should have an appropriate generric type parameter.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll go through them one by one but I have an answer to your first question. _You take the first stateModel, but what if they are not ordered by date?_ Good observation, but I am sure that they are sorted by date, so (purely) for optimization purposes I'm not re-checking.

Comment: I'm going to be testing your changes. One thing I'm going to add right afterwards (after I've taken benchmarks) is to store the properties in a singleton dictionary where the key is the Type, such that getting the properties through reflection happens only once for each entity.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti: Sound good, if I understand you right. When done, you could consider to post an self-answer, with the updated code.

Comment: Ah that's what you usually do? I was going to edit my original post. OK.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti: Yes, It's done now and then that way. On the other hand you are not allowed to edit the question, when answers are posted, because that would invalidate them.

Comment: I'll post my code soon, as soon as I fix an issue. I can't understand why I am calling the method in this way: `myList.AddRange(TimeWindow.CalculateTimeWindows(dateFrom, dateTo, myList).ToList());` where myList would be an empty list, and I'd have 16 lines like this (for different lists, all of which are empty), and the code is taking approximately 4.5 seconds to run, despite that I have this: `if (stateModels.Count() == 0) return new List<T>();` at the very top of the `CalculateTimeWindows` method.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti: I can't tell you what the problem is with empty lists. I sounds strange. But I think, if the gap between dateFrom and dateTo is too large it will slow the calculations drastically.

Comment: the gap between dateFrom and dateTo is always 24 hours, and in this case (empty lists) should not make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

### Alternative approach

Instead of using attributes and reflection, I'd go for a set of generic methods that take type-specific date and value-selector methods as parameters.

First, a method that returns items grouped by time segment:

```
public static IEnumerable<TimeSegmentItems<T>> GetItemsPerTimeSegment(
    IEnumerable<T> items,
    DateTime from,
    DateTime to,
    TimeSpan segmentDuration,
    Func<T, DateTime> getTimestamp) { ... }

// Contains all items within a given time segment,
// as well as the last item from the preceding time segment
// (that item determines the initial state):
public class TimeSegmentItems<T>
{
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Then, a utility method for obtaining the dominant value for a given time segment:

```
public static TValue GetDominantValue<TItem, TValue>(
    IEnumerable<TItem> items,
    DateTime from,
    DateTime to,
    Func<TItem, DateTime> getTimestamp,
    Func<TItem, TValue> getValue) { ... }
```

Together, they allow you to do the following:

```
GetItemsPerTimeSegment(myValues, fromDate, toDate, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), m => m.Date)
    .Select(segment => new MyModel {
        Value = GetDominantValue(segment.Items, segment.Start, segment.End, m => m.Date, m => m.Value),
        ActuallyAnEnum = GetDominantValue(segment.Items, segment.Start, segment.End, m => m.Date, m => m.ActuallyAnEnum),
    });
```

Which can further be streamlined, but that's the gist of it.

### Comparison

Comparing this to your original approach:

- Reflection and `dynamic` are both relatively slow, and especially with `dynamic` you lose compile-time checking. This approach should be more succinct, more robust and (much) faster.
- With attributes, you are limited to types that you can add attributes to. This approach lets you work with any type, and even create different 'views' for the same type, at the cost of having to write type-specific logic (the date and value selectors, and the final result-building code).
- Instead of a single public method that does everything, these utility methods each focus on a specific task, which makes them more reusable. You can swap the dominant-value logic for average-value logic without having to touch the time-segment grouping logic. You can also build an attribute/reflection-based layer on top of this that removes the need for type-specific code, if necessary.

Comment: I would also focus on an alternative than to analyse the OP's code for refactoring.

Comment: It depends. If you want to include another property then yes, you'll need to add a `GetDominantValue` call for that - similar to how, with your approach, you'd need to add an attribute to that property. If you rename a property or change its type then no manual changes are required.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure I understand. I have fixed the problems with reflection (I think) by storing the results in a concurrent dictionary (code posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/performance-issue-with-empty-lists). What I don't understand with your solution is whether or not I would need to edit some code whenever the database models change. That was the idea behind using reflection, to avoid problems with developers forgetting to also do changes elsewhere.

Comment: I see @PieterWitvoet, thanks, I'll give it some thought, though to be honest I still think it's more difficult for myself and colleagues to forget making a call to `GetDominantValue` than adding an attribute to a property given that all the lines above and below it would have attributes.

Comment: That makes sense. As I said, you can still put an attribute-based layer on top of these methods if necessary. You'd still benefit from a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 4):

I found something that looks really weird to me

> ```
>     for (i = 0; i < dictionary.Dictionary.Count; i++)
>     {
>         maxValue = dictionary.Dictionary.First();
>         for (j = 1; j < dictionary.Dictionary.Count; j++)
>         {
>             var valuePair = dictionary.Dictionary.ElementAt(j);
>
>             if (valuePair.Value > maxValue.Value)
>                 maxValue = valuePair;
>         }
>     }
>     var valToSet = maxValue.Key.Item;
> ```

This looks like it could be replaced with

```
var valToSet = dictionary.Values.Max();
```

if you are trying to get the key with the max value you could use this

```
var valToSet = dictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;
```

found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508315/1214743 be sure to test around values that are the same.

---

I also found something else that I would do differently as well

> ```
>   if (sameAsPrevious)
>   {
>       var prevVal = GetValue(prevTimeWindow, dictionary.Name);
>
>       if (valToSet == null && prevVal == null)
>       { }
>       else if ((valToSet == null && prevVal != null) || (valToSet != null && prevVal == null) || !valToSet.Equals(prevVal))
>           sameAsPrevious = false;
>   }
> ```

your if/else statement could be written like this:

```
if (valToSet == null && prevVal == null)
{ 
}
else
{
    sameAsPrevious = (valToSet == preval);
}
```

because

- if `valToSet` is null and the other has a value it won't be the same, it also works the other way around.  This would make `sameAsPrevious == false`
- if they are both null they get caught in the initial if statement
- if they are both have a value and it is the same we want the `sameAsPrevious` value to be `true` anyway.  if `valToSet == preval` will set `sameAsPrevious` to true, which it should be in that situation.

Comment: I am sure you mean `!(valToSet != preval)` or `valToSet == preval`. Or what is `!(valToSet <> preval)`?

Comment: Cheers I'll run some tests on both today :)

That first part looks really weird to me too. I wrote the code over a year ago and to be honest I can't understand what I was doing there either, because it seems to me like there's an extra loop `for (i = 0; i < dictionary.Dictionary.Count; i++)` which seems like it's completely useless.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that for the first part you meant `var valToSet = dictionary.Dictionary.Max().Key.Item;`

Comment: _I can't understand what I was doing there either_ o_O so how can we? @MarkCiliaVincenti

Comment: @t3chb0t :P :P :P

Comment: I implemented these two and did one process that generally takes practically 2 hours (with only part of this being the time window processing) and it took 1.1 hours instead, so I think this made a significant difference. However, I still don't understand why sometimes it takes 200ms and sometimes over 30 seconds, even though it had only some 12 rows to process!

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti, dictionaries hold `<key, value>` Pairs, and it appears the you want the max value out of the dictionary,  if that is the case, then the key doesn't really matter.

Comment: @dfhwze, thank you for pointing that out, I put the not equals from SQL in there and see what you mean...oops.  it is fixed now

Comment: @Malachi I have an issue getting your first change to work actually. The only code I can see is the one that is commented out in my code, but I would usually comment something out because it wasn't working properly.

Comment: When I get back to my laptop I will edit the past. You still need the foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries) unless you are setting the valToSet variable to a key, value pair, then you would need to grab the pair for the max value

Comment: Gentle reminder @Malachi

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I am not sure what you mean.  what isn't working?  I edited my answer.  the `foreach` wasn't part of my review, the nested `for` loops were part of my review.  what isn't working, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Malachi, there is no property `.maxValue()` on a Dictionary.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti, I cannot find where I saw the usage so I will edit my answer

Comment: @Malachi, valToSet is not supposed to be set to the dictionary value (which is a count) but to the inner item of the dictionary key. It's of type dynamic. I previously had `var valToSet = dictionary.Dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(dictionary.Dictionary.Values.Max())).Key.Item;` but for some reason it wasn't working as expected.

Comment: @Malachi, I shortened it to `var valToSet = dictionary.Dictionary.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key.Item;`

Comment: So you want the key of the highest value?